# Generate documentation from background image, text and screenshots

Tags: documentation-generator

I'm trying to create a set of User Manuals for a fairly large product that changes frequently. To save myself the hassle of editing the documentation all the time to update screenshots, I'm looking for a solution I can code once and reuse. There are currently ~50 documents planned for small components of the product.

I have the following at the moment:

- An A4 branded template (header / footer) for each page in the generated PDF
- The text I would like in the document. I have not yet annotated the text with page breaks, but it does have references to screenshots in the format: `!image|image-name.png!` - this can be changed with a find/replace
- The screenshots to inject

Are there any programs - Windows or Linux - that can take the template, stick the text in the whitespace (I can give dimensions for whitespace) and replace the !image|image-name.png! with the actual image? Ideally I'd be able to run this from the command line as part of a build process.

I'm open to paying for the functionality or, if it doesn't exist, building something to do just this.

The output format would ideally be PDF

Comment: What is your input file format? Microsoft Word .docx? I once had a similar issue and solved it with [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/). Maybe I could write a small tool for you.

Comment: What budget? About how many pages of documentation do you want to create, a few dozens or a few thousands?